# How to render random backgrounds with HTML5 Scratch Card

Tags: javascript, html, random, scratchcard

I am using HTML5 Scratch Card plugin and dont know how I can render random backgrounds with javascript.Here is the code

```
window.onload = function() {
            createScratchCard({
                'container':document.getElementById('circle'),
                'background':'assets/images/demo2-circle-background.png',
                'foreground':'assets/images/demo2-circle-foreground.png',
                'percent':100,
                'coin':'assets/images/coin2.png',
                'thickness':18,
            });
        }
```

So with this default structure how I can render random 2, 3 images and show one every time, show randomly>

Comment: Well it depends on how you named your files. e.g if you name it `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, then you just have to change the background line to  `'background':'assets/images/'+Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)+'.png',`

Comment: ohhh good idea..but if not, if I want to have normal names?

Comment: it didnt work 'background':'assets/images/'+Math.floor(Math.random()*yourArray.length),, the first one work perfectly

Comment: Oups my bad it should have been `'background':'assets/images/'+ yourArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*yourArray.length)],`

Comment: Now it reneders the same image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set all your file's names into an array and pick one randomly each time.

To make sure your user won't get the same value every time they come to your page, the only solution is to save it somewhere on their side. For this you could use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), or as chosen in the above example [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)  :

```
window.onload = function() {
  // declare your file names
  var theFiles = ["foo.png", "bar.png", "baz.png"];
  // get the saved number we got
  var previous = localStorage.getItem('rolledDices');
  if(previous){
     // parse them and remove them from our array
     var p = previous.split(' ');
     if(p.length-1<theFiles.length){
       p.forEach(function(i){if(i!=='')theFiles.splice(theFiles.indexOf(i),1)})
       }
     // clear the storage if we got all of them
     else{
        previous='';
        }
     }
  // get a new random value from our array
  var randomFn = theFiles[Math.floor(Math.random()*theFiles.length)];
  // add it to the list of saved ones
  localStorage.setItem('rolledDices', (previous||'')+' '+randomFn);

  createScratchCard({
    'container':document.getElementById('circle'),
    'background':'assets/images/'+randomFn,
    'foreground':'assets/images/demo2-circle-foreground.png',
    'percent':100,
    'coin':'assets/images/coin2.png',
    'thickness':18,
    });
  }
```

Comment: now it renders first two, havent rendered the third one

Comment: how many tries? you're just picking a random number through 3 variables, you may fall a lot of times on the two sames

Comment: Running `var theFiles = ["foo.png", "bar.png", "baz.png"]; theFiles[Math.floor(Math.random()*theFiles.length)]` in my console 10 times I got every of the three possibilities

Comment: yes I see but I need to exclue the times that they are getting 1.jpg again 1jpg for example

Comment: If this code is ran at page load only, then your only solution is to save somewhere ( localStorage or cookie) on user's device what number they got and pop it out of the array before. If this is not at the page load, then simply call `theFiles.pop(Math.floor(Math.random()*theFiles.length))` which will remove the called index of the array (so at third time it will be empty : to counter taht, you can create a copy of this array by slicing it before poping anything and if the array is empty then refill it with the saved one)

Comment: it should be changed on page load page refreshing

Comment: Ok I'll add something in the answer then